# LTspice OTA simulation does not work

Tags: analog, ltspice, design, cmos, ota

I am trying to simulate a balanced OTA with TSMC 350 nm technology in LTspice. [Here](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/icdesign/ee241_s00/ASSIGNMENTS/TSMC035-n96g-params.txt) is the TSMC 350 nm library for LTspice. I designed the balanced OTA topology below:

[image]

[image]

Thd output current is almost zero. I've tried various W/L ratios, but the result is the same.

I expected a result like below:

[image]

I can't figure out where my fault is. Is the library file incorrect, or maybe the W/L ratio? Why is the output current almost zero?

Comment: You have no load.  Where would the output current go?

Comment: That's what took my time... :/

Comment: You might also want to connect M1 & M2 bodies to VSS if this is intended to go on an actual CMOS process.